# Try/catch and tail position (ES6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is the call to `bar` in tail position?

```
function foo() {
    try        { return bar()   }
    catch(err) { <do-something> }        
}
```

I attempted to find the answer in ES6, but didn't find what I was looking for.

UPDATE

Felix Kling points to the this section of the standard:

```
TryStatement : try Block Catch
    1. Return HasProductionInTailPosition of Catch with argument nonterminal.

TryStatement: tryBlockFinally
TryStatement: tryBlockCatchFinally
    1. Return HasProductionInTailPosition of Finally with argument nonterminal.

Catch : catch (CatchParameter) Block
    1. Return HasProductionInTailPosition of Block with argument nonterminal.
```

This means that the call to `bar` in the example is not in tail position.

Comment: Doesn't look like it: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-statement-rules . But I could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: IMO answers don't belong in the question.

Answer (score 4):

A tail position can be defined as the final action of a function.

The problem with `try/catch` in this case is a branch where both the last statement in the `try` and the last statement in the `catch` can be considered tail. With this in mind, I'd say the answer is no, `bar` is not in tail position. We could say though that `bar` is a tail call within the `try` block itself - each block could have it's own tail call depending on how strictly we define what a tail is.

Another implication here is that, when using a `try/catch`, we have to be able to jump back to the `catch` block at any point down the call stack. This means there also can't be a tail optimization because we have to maintain the necessary call stack.

Comment: I agree that there is a need to store information on where the execution must proceed in case an exception is thrown - and that's problematic with respect to tail calling `bar`. The entire stack is not needed though - only the stack that led to the execution of `foo` is needed (but I guess that point is moot :-) )

Comment: @soegaard haha yup but you're right, I corrected my answer :)